# Using here-strings and split function in PowerShell 5.1

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to split a here-strings value to use in invoke-command but it throws what appears to be an empty item in the array. Which seems to cause errors when trying to use in other commands like `invoke-command`

```
$csv = @"
    computer1,
    computer2
"@
        
$csv.Split(',')
```

Output:

```
computer1,

computer2
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the surrounding whitespace from the array elements resulting from the `.Split()` call, which includes the newline that precedes the second element:

```bash
$csv.Split(',').Trim()  # -> @('computer1', 'computer2')
```

Note that, thanks to PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration), the `.Trim()` method call is applied to *each element* of the array resulting from the `.Split()` call.

> what appears to be an empty item in the array

No, there's no empty item, but the *newline* following `computer1,` is *included* in the 2nd resulting array element, because you're splitting by `,` only.

---

Note that in your simple case, where the tokens do not contain whitespace themselves, you can simply omit the `,` separators and use the unary form of the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator:

```bash
# No separators - each computer name on its own line.
$csv = @"
  computer1
  computer2
"@

# Unary -split splits by arbitrary runs of whitespace, and
# ignores leading and trailing whitespace.
-split $csv # -> @('computer1', 'computer2')
```

Use `$csv -split '\r?\n'` to split by newlines only (which preserves intra-line whitespace, which could be removed with `($csv -split '\r?\n').Trim()`).